# How to ignore the parent node of an XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml, nodes

Here is my XML file

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy rotation="0">
    <node class="A">
        <node class="B"/>
        <node class="C"/>
        <node class="D"/>
    </node>
</hierarchy>
```

Can anyone tell me the java code to ignore the node with `class="A"`? I just want the child nodes which end with `/>` and read their attribute values. I am using `DocumentBuilderFactory` class in java for the above scenario.

Comment: consider only those elements which doesn't have any child.

Comment: But how I even tried (!(nodeObject.hasChildNodes())) but its not working

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    final String xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>"
    + "<hierarchy rotation=\"0\">"
    + "<node class=\"A\">"
    + "<node class=\"B\"/>"
    + "<node class=\"C\"/>"
    + "<node class=\"D\"/>"
    + "</node>"
    + "</hierarchy>";

    final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    final InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
    final Document document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
    final NodeList childNodes = document.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        final Node childNode = childNodes.item(i);
        System.out.println("childNode[" + i + "].getAttributes(): " + toStringAttributes(childNode));
    }
}

private static String toStringAttributes(Node childNode) {
    String attributesString = "[";
    final NamedNodeMap attributes = childNode.getAttributes();

    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
        final Node node = attributes.item(i);
        attributesString += node.getNodeName();
        attributesString += "=";
        attributesString += "\"" + node.getNodeValue() + "\"";
        if (i < attributes.getLength() - 1) {
            attributesString += ",";
        }
    }
    attributesString += "]";
    return attributesString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig it worked fine for me , But this is not working if there are multiple parent nodes like this example

 final String xmlString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>"
     + "<hierarchy rotation=\"0\">"
     + "<node class=\"A\">"
     + "<node class=\"B\"/>"
     + "<node class=\"C\"/>"
     + "<node class=\"D\"/>"
     + "</node>"
     + "<node class=\"E\">"
     + "<node class=\"F\"/>"
     + "<node class=\"G\"/>"
     + "<node class=\"H\"/>"
     + "</node>"
     + "</hierarchy>";